# Is it possible to write a general procedure that "pre-loads" all images and videos in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

So I'm making a slideshow that includes many `img` and `video` elements, some of which are large and so I want to "pre-load" all media assets so they don't have to load when you scroll to the slide they're on.

Now, from what I understand, to get a `img` element to truly load you need to "use" it and the hack for that is basically

```
var url = $myimg.attr('src');
$myimg.attr('src') = '';
$myimg.attr('src') = url;
```

So I know that I can pre-load all images with

```
function LoadMediaAssets ( )
{
    var $imgs = $('img'),
        k = 0;
    for ( var k = 0; k < $imgs.length; ++k ) 
    {
        var $img = $($imgs[k]), 
            url = $img.attr('src'); 
        $img.attr('src') = '';
        $img.attr('src') = url;
    }
}
```

My question is how I would add `video`s into the mix. How do you pre-load videos? Like this?

```
function LoadMediaAssets ( )
{
    var $imgs = $('img'),
        $vids = $('video'),
        k = 0, 
        n = $imgs.length + $vids.length;
    for ( var k = 0; k < $imgs.length; ++k ) 
    {
        var $img = $($imgs[k]), 
            url = $img.attr('src'); 
        $img.attr('src') = '';
        $img.attr('src') = url;
        console.log("Progress : " + (++k/n * 100) + "%");
    }
    for ( var k = 0; k < $vids.length; ++k ) 
    {
        var $src = $($vids[k]).find('source'), 
            url = $src.attr('src'); 
        $src.attr('src') = '';
        $src.attr('src') = url;
        console.log("Progress : " + (($imgs.length + (++k))/n * 100) + "%");
    }
}
```

Is there an entirely better way to do this?

Comment: You can test this yourself using the network inspector dev tool. Try creating a `<video>` element in JavaScript but don't add it to the DOM. If you see a network request for the video resource, then you know it's being "preloaded" as expected.

Comment: What's wrong with having it in the DOM?

Comment: He's trying to help you answer your question by creating the element and loading the content in JavaScript, to determine if it can be preloaded before it is needed in the DOM.